# Deploy a git repo to a Windows VM on azure

Tags: git, azure, azure-virtual-machine, repo

I'm running Node.js through IISNode on a Windows Virtual Machine on Azure, to do processing of vector drawing files.

I'm quite the newbie when it comes to IIS and Windows servers (this project requires Windows).

What's the best way for me to be able to deploy a Git repo on the server?  (Push to a remote repo on the server) Should I run an SSH server on the VM? Perhaps there are ready solutions for this on Azure already?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge, there are so many ways to deploy a git server on Azure. However, for your scenario, you need to use Windows for your deploying. **This should be same as deploy git server on a local windows machine**. I suggest you could consider following solutions:

1. Build you Git server step by step by referring [this blog](https://elegantcode.com/2011/06/18/git-on-windows-creating-a-network-shared-central-repository/).
2. Using [Bonobo Git Server](https://bonobogitserver.com/) to set up your own self hosted git server on IIS for Windows directly.

I don't which one is the best practice for you. It depends on your requirement.

Additional, don't forget open specific ports on the NSG.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.

Comment: Hi,@FrankSandqvist. If this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as answer  so that we can help more people. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I'll do that. As for what ended up doing: I wanted to avoid the overhead of 'running a server on my server', so I set up an endpoint/ hook on my API I can visit with my auth details, that automatically pulls my Git repo and resets the server (using nodegit). The node server itself basically rewrites itself.